# Is there an easily searchable database of hardware that works with Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, hardware-certification

I'm looking to buy a new custom-built laptop and I want to know that the hardware will work.

Do Canonical provide any tools so that would-be users can check if their hardware works? I've seen the certification website but this focusses on whole systems from massive companies; it does not have the detail I need.

I need to know about

- wireless: Intel Centrino N 2230
- Clevo W550SU1 chassis with Intel 8 series chipset http://www.fortunetechnology.com/view/3877/

for 12.04

But the question is a general one about a searchable database provided by Ubuntu. (Obviously I have heard of Google.)

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, but have a look at this ~
http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/ and from the list, you might be able to get something there. :)

Note: When I bought a laptop 2 years ago, I brought with me a USB with Ubuntu on it so I could test run and see if the hardware works.

Comment: Thanks, but no, that's the site I was referring to as the one that focusses on whole systems from major manufacturers. I'm having a custom one built, so need to know about things at a part level.

Comment: @artfulrobot: What you're looking for is like a most giant server with a database containing all the hardware parts in the world, and capable or running simulations of all hardware combinations possible. It would be much cheaper to order your parts via internet, put the them together and test it yourself. Return the products within legal period time if not satisfied with results. Such giant server you want would put the Human Genome Project to shame!

Answer (score 1):

Here you will find the info for the wireless : 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported
(I know that it's only a small part of the answer you're looking for).

Comment: Thanks Laurent, I notice the wifi card is not listed there, but it is reported elsewhere as working, so I don't think much effort is put into making that a comprehensive list.